# Intellij dependency broke due to no bundle file

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jar, dependencies, bundle

Recently I encounter a issue maybe related to this. When project imported, there is a issue regarding not being able to find a maven dependency within ./m2 location. However, there is a .jar there. The problem is that Intellij insist to look for .bundle file rather than .jar file. Any solution for that?

Library Maven: org.apache.directory.jdbm:apacheds-jdbm1:bundle:2.0.0-M2 has broken classes path:   /Users/Aertoria/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/jdbm/apacheds-jdbm1/2.0.0-M2/apacheds-jdbm1-2.0.0-M2.bundle

Comment: Does it build/run from the command line Maven? How is that dependency defined in `pom.xml`?

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder.
mvn install from command line everything is working.
in pom.xml, it is defined as a dependency of a dependency, just like a normal <dependency>

Comment: Have you created the project from the pom? Does this materially affect your ability to work on the project, or is it just a warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be encountering [IDEA-117578 Dependency with type "bundle" isn't resolved correctly](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117578).

It's possible you can work around it by explicitly adding it as a `jar` dependency to your project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.jdbm</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-jdbm1</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I thought about it too. But it is actually very hard. All pom changes will have a diff with that big project. Do you know anyway i can achieve the goal of both worlds?